# Put values from one row to other rows in view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view (V1) that looks like this with the source table T1:

| Number | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 0,05 |
| 2 | car | 0,08 |
| 1 | table | 0,01 |
| 2 | table | 0,07 |

Basically i want to copy all values from that have the Number 1 to all rows that have the same type.

| Number | Type | Value | New_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 0,05 | 0,05 |
| 2 | car | 0,08 | 0,05 |
| 1 | table | 0,01 | 0,01 |
| 2 | table | 0,07 | 0,01 |

I found a solution that actually works:

```
Alter View V1 AS

Select *, map.New_Value from T
left Join (Select * from T1 Where Number = 1)map ON T.Type = map.Type
```

Unfortunatly I have to repeat this step several times, after i made calculations based on the self join before. As a result I would have to adjust the code like this

```
Alter View V1 AS
Select *, map3.another_new_Value
from(
Select *, map.New_Value from T
left Join (Select * from T1 Where Number = 1)map ON T.Type = map.Type) map2


left Join (Select * from T1 Where Number = 1)map3 ON map2.Type = map3.Type
```

The result is, that my code is growing exponentially... I need to repeat this 10 times.
The only way to handle the grwoth with this procedure is to create several views.

That is the reason why I wanted to ask, if someone has an idea how to fill the New_Value field without using a self join.

Maybe another helpful info: The Value of the rows with number 1 is always the lowest value for that type.

KR

Comment: Why not just nuse `FIRST_VALUE`?

Comment: It is unclear, when reading your question where the table `T` has it's origin/.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
Select 
   T1.*, 
   T2.Number as New_Value
from T1
left Join T1 as T2 on T1.Type=T2.Type and T2.Number=1
```

Above assumes that every `Type` as a row with Number=1, so the `left join` could actually be an `inner join`.

But, because I am still using the `left join` you will see the `NULL` value for Type's that do no have a Number=1 row.

(How the `NULL` value is show is dependent on the client your are using)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Alter View V1 AS

Select *, (SELECT VALUE FROM T WHERE T.TYPE=ALIAS.TYPE AND NUMBER=1) AS NEWVALUE from T ALIAS
```

If there is a possibility of having multiple entries with NUMBER=1 for a particular type, you can use max(VALUE) in the select subquery.